# Craft CMS plugin with AJAX gives 404 error

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, controller

I have created a small craft cms plugin to pull some information from the DB, and everytime I execute the plugin I get a 404.

Here is the controller

```
namespace Craft;

class UserExists_UserControllerController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionGetUser()
    {
        $this->returnJson($response);
    }
}
```

And this is the jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ url("actions/userexists/usercontroller/getUser") }}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: I've answered below, but wanted to offer one other (unrelated) recommendation: Your class's name can be shortened to `UserExists_UserController`—I suggest, only because the use or omission of the word "controller" in actions may become confusing! Using this class name will allow your AJAX call to be made to `actions/userexists/user/getUser`, instead.

Comment: Another possibility is to use a top-level controller—if your plugin isn't apt to have many other controllers or actions, you could simplify the naming even further: `UserExists_Controller`, and access it via `actions/userexists/getUser`.

Comment: I'm concerned, though, that the 404 error you're getting may have something to do with the naming of the file and class. Could you pots the filename that you've defined `UserExists_UserControllerController` in?

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for your reply. I have done that i keep getting 404

Comment: Do you mean UserExistsPlugin.php ?

Comment: That is your base plugin definition file. Your plugin folder should also have a `controllers` directory, containing `UserExists_UsersController.php`, which defines the class `UserExists_UsersController`. Action methods in that class will be available at `actions/userexists/users/getUser`.

Comment: Take a look at https://pluginfactory.io if you're having trouble with the overall plugin structure—it'll mock out a clean starting point for you.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't currently logged in, you're apt to be running up against the "anonymous access" limitation.

[This section of the Controller documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#allowing-anonymous-access-to-actions) should help:

> By default, controller actions are only accessible to logged-in users. You can override that by changing the protected `$allowAnonymous` property on your controller class. To allow anonymous access to all of your controller’s actions, set it to `true`:

```php
<?php
namespace Craft;

class CocktailRecipes_IngredientsController extends BaseController
{
  protected $allowAnonymous = true;

  // Your action methods
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you... I tried that it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Two things to try:

1) Try to use the Craft.getActionUrl() to get the URL of the action, as per the documentation for [Linking Directly to Controller Actions](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers#linking-directly-to-controller-actions):

2) Make sure there is no `$this->requireLogin()` or `$this->requirePostRequest()` in your controller

Theoretically there could be something wrong in the routing as well, as I have also experienced that a plugin runs perfectly, but because the response was not set to reply or re-route to somewhere meaningful, I got a 404 when accessing the controller via URL, and not from the control panel. In that case, this answered question could be helpful: [Controller action works but still gives 404](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5401/controller-action-works-but-still-gives-404).

Comment: Thaank you!!... that links sounds interesting... I will have a look

Answer (score 1):

If you are still not having any luck, If none of the above work, [check out this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12736/how-can-i-call-a-controller-method-from-the-front-end-using-ajax) that shows how to call an ajax function from a controller.

Comment: I have seen that thread I made it look the same and nothing... but thaaanks!

Comment: Try making your ajax request path start with a `/`. Example: `/actions/pluginHandle/checkStatus`